# What exactly is happening when I run `netctl-auto enable-all`?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, netctl

My wifi connection has been dying very regularly.  I notice when I run `netctl-auto enable-all` I reconnect within 5 seconds every time. (My connection has dropped twice while posting this.)

Why does this work, and what does this suggest about the actual problem?  How can I solve this for good?

If you need more info, please ask and I'll gladly supply it.

`IWCONFIG` output:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"NETGEAR30"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 44:94:xx:xx:xx:xx   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:906  Invalid misc:12   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

---

`lspci -nnk | grep -i -A5 network` output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:c162]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

---

The last 20 lines of `dmesg`:

```
[    4.054881] systemd-journald[118]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.262104] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.262246] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    4.274116] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    8.058666] wlp3s0: authenticate with 00:0f:xx:xx:xx:xx
[    8.060065] wlp3s0: send auth to 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[    8.061828] wlp3s0: authenticated
[    8.061941] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[    8.063395] wlp3s0: associate with 00:0f:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[    8.067304] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 00:0f:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[    8.068513] wlp3s0: associated
[    8.068542] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   15.848000] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[  217.763444] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  221.502417] wlp3s0: authenticate with 44:94:xx:xx:xx:xx
[  221.503254] wlp3s0: send auth to 44:94:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[  221.505078] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  221.506711] wlp3s0: associate with 44:94:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[  221.510277] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 44:94:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=10)
[  221.512033] wlp3s0: associated
```

---

`lshw -c network` output:

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 20:1a:06:78:84:ae
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:60 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 6b
       serial: 5c:51:4f:51:b0:d5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.12.9-2-ARCH firmware=22.1.7.0 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:61 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Comment: I think the output of `iwconfig` and `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i -A5 network` would be awesome. Also, make sure that you are near the access point.

Comment: I don't think it tells us really anything useful towards debugging the underlying issue. Debugging wifi issues is notoriously difficult. Please provide this output: `lshw -c network` & take a look at `dmesg` when this issue arises. Include that as well, just the last 20 or so lines should suffice for `dmesg`. We'll likely be asking for more info so don't get frustrated, debugging these issues is a "process".

Comment: @Braiam done, and done.

Comment: @sim okay, done.

Comment: @KorganRivera - the output from `dmesg` is that from when the card started to act up and drop?

Comment: @sim It was about 10 minutes after I posted the original message, and it had dropped twice while typing the original message.  So, yes.

Comment: @KorganRivera - sorry I need it to be exactly right at that moment when it drops out on you. I'm looking for potential error msgs. when this happens from the kernel modules. I suspect that they are crashing since that's typically what happens in this scenario. The msgs. would be from `iwlagn` similar to my blog post: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6049/debugging-an-intermittently-dropping-intel-wireless-n-1000-network-card-on-fedora-14/